# Why does Entity Framework database-first not create a virtual property for some of my foreign keys?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, virtual

I have a SQL Server table with 7 foreign key relationships. When Entity Framework 
built the class that represents the table, it only created 3 virtual navigation properties of the foreign key connected tables and missed the other 4.

For example, let's say I have a table 1 with the following columns:

```
Column 1 (PK)  
Column 1 (FK to table 2)  
Column 1 (FK to table 3)  
Column 1 (FK to table 4)
```

Entity Framework then created these virtual properties in the `Table_1.cs`:

```
public virtual table_2 table_2 { get; set; }  
public virtual table_3 table_3 { get; set; }
```

Why would Entity Framework not create a virtual property for the fourth foreign 
key connected table?

Thanks in advance.

Here is some information about the database:

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_7] FOREIGN KEY([FK_3]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table_7] ([FK_3]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_7]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_4] FOREIGN KEY([original_bill_billing_period])
REFERENCES [dbo].[table_4] ([billing_period]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_4]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_3] FOREIGN KEY([charge_type]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table_3] ([code]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_3]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_5] FOREIGN KEY([status]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table_5] ([code]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_5]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_2] FOREIGN KEY([FK_2], [FK_1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table_2] ([FK_2], [FK_1]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_2]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_6] FOREIGN KEY([service]) REFERENCES [dbo].[table_6] ([service_code]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table_1_table_6]
GO

The tables that have virtual navigation properies are table_3, table_5, and table_6. Why did entity framework skip the other 3 tables?

Comment: Please post your database schema and foreign-key constraint declarations.

Comment: Are all referenced classes part of the entity model?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes.